# Genereric.List to a Dictionary/List

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have a method that I receive a FormCollection. And I need to pass to my application layer a list of it.

What I'm doing and works:

```
var formIndexes = form.AllKeys.Select((e, i) => new { Name = e, Index = i }).Where(o => o.Name.Contains("StatusId")).ToList();
var formValues = formIndexes.Select(e => new { Value = form[e.Index], Name = e.Name }).ToList();
```

but formValues is a Generic.List and I need to convert to a List or a Dictionary.

Error:
**cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: string Value, string Name>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>'**

**[SOLVED]**

As @DanielA.White said, I solved doing:

```
formIndexes.Select(e => new { Value = form[e.Index], Name = e.Name }).ToDictionary(a => a.Name, b => b.Value);
```

Comment: linq has `ToDictionary()`

Comment: @DanielA.White thanks!! Solved doing formIndexes.Select(e => new { Value = form[e.Index], Name = e.Name }).ToDictionary(a => a.Name, b => b.Value);

Answer (score 1):

According to the error text, the final result should be a dictionary, not a list. test this

```
var formValues = formIndexes.ToDictionary(x => x.Index, x => x.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

FormcCollection, if you check the source, has already accessors set.
So it can be accessed as a dictionary without need to convert it:

```
        [HttpPost] 
        public ActionResult Submit(FormCollection fc)
        {
            ViewBag.Id = fc["Id"];
            ViewBag.Name = fc["Name"];
            bool chk = Convert.ToBoolean(fc["Addon"].Split(',')[0]);
            ViewBag.Addon = chk;

            return View("Index");
        }
```

Check [here](https://www.completecsharptutorial.com/asp-net-mvc5/formcollection-object-in-asp-net-mvc-with-example.php#:%7E:text=A%20FormCollection%20Object%20is%20used,easily%20accessed%20in%20action%20method.) for further explanation